# yacc same value returned

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a grammar like this :

```
S : value1 ':' value2 ';' {printf("%s %s",$1,$3);};
```

input : Hello : World ;

output : Hello Hello

value1 and value2 are both Strings.

The probleme is that $3 is returning the same value as $1 and I can't find the reason.

Comment: It's almost certainly because you wrote `yylval = yytext` in your flex action. You **must** make a copy of the token string if you want to use it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i just forgot to update the yylval in value2.